# Which of the following option is true?

Tags: real-analysis

$\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists \delta>0$ such that 
$|f(x)-f(x_0)|>\varepsilon$ whenever $|x-x_0|>\delta$ is equivalent to which of the following?

$1.f$ is unbounded.

$2.\lim_{|x|\to\infty}|f(x)|=\infty$

I try the example $f(x)=x$ but in this example both options are true.I do not know how to prove or disprove them.

Comment: Option 2 implies option 1, so try something that satisfies 1, but not 2.

Comment: Hint: fix an arbitrary $f(x_0)$, so for any $\epsilon\gg 1$ you can find $x$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)|\geq \epsilon\gg 1$. Can this function be bounded?

Comment: @DanielFischer I do not have such example in my mind.Can you give some one?

Comment: My thinking is that $f$ is unbounded.

Comment: $x\cdot \sin^2 x$ is one.

Comment: I believe that the stronger statement, option (2), holds. Have a look at $f(x) = \tan{x}$ which is unbounded but does not satisfy the given condition, so answer (1) is not equivalent.  It remains for you to prove that answer (2) *is* equivalent.

Comment: $x \cdot \sin^2 x$ does not satisfy the given condition because no matter how large a $\delta$ you choose, there are places with $x>\delta$ where $f(x) = f(x_0) = 0$. So "$f$ is unbounded" does not imply the condition, and can't be equivalent.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think your example works.So $1$ is true and $2$ is false?

Comment: @Flip No. It shows that the condition is not satisfied by all unbounded functions, so it cannot be equivalent to 1. Hence 2. is the only remaining candidate.

Comment: Neither 1. nor 2. implies the property.

Comment: @Did If $x_0$ is fixed, 2. does. I think that was in the original statement, and OP just forgot to mention it because it was mistakenly deemed irrelevant.

Comment: @DanielFischer Right.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, (2) is equivalent to the property $P$:

Proof that $(2) \Rightarrow P$:

$$\lim_{|x| \rightarrow \infty} |f(x)| = \infty \Longrightarrow
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} |f(x)| = \infty \wedge \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} |f(x)| = \infty
$$
So (2) implies that (a) for any given $\eta$ there exists a $\delta_a(\eta)$ such that for all $x >\delta_a$, $|f(x)| > \eta$; and that (b) for any given $\eta$ there exists b $\delta_b(\eta)$ such that for all $x <\delta_b$, $|f(x)| > \eta$.

Then for any given $\epsilon$ choose 
$$\delta(\epsilon) = \max \left( \delta_a(\eta = \epsilon+|f(x_0)|),
 \delta_b(\eta = \epsilon+|f(x_0)|) \right)
$$ and this $\epsilon$ demonstrates the given property $P$.

Proof that $P \Rightarrow (2)$:

Write (2) as replacing $\epsilon$ by $\eta$ and $\delta$ by $\delta_P$. Then for any given $\epsilon$ testing (2), choose $\delta_a = \delta_P (\epsilon + |f(x_0)|)$, demonstrating part (a) of (2).  And  choose $\delta_b = \delta_P (\epsilon + |f(x_0)|)$, demonstrating part (b) of (2).  THus $P$ implies both parts of proposition (2).

So $(2) \Longrightarrow P \Longrightarrow (2)$ hence $P \Longleftrightarrow (2)$.

Comment: @Flip The way to say 'thanks' is voting the answer.